# MooTools: How to Request and Evaluate javascript on a button click

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

I am using mootools v1.3. I added a click event to button with id as "submit_details". All I want is to load an another mootools script on button click event and execute it. I tried a way as below

```
$('submit_details').addEvent('click',function(){
   alert('checkepoint-1');
   myScript = new Asset.javascript('js/main.js',{});
   alert('checkepoint-2');
});
```

But its not working.(It alerts only "checkepoint-1").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using without new keyword.

```
$('submit_details').addEvent('click',function(){
   alert('checkepoint-1');
   myScript = Asset.javascript('js/main.js',{});
   alert('checkepoint-2');
});
```

For more details, check here.

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets

Comment: Asset is a part of mootools-more. make sure that your version of -more is "compiled" with Assets.js included. Also, this is async so you may want to pass `{onload: function() { ... stuff that depends on main.js }` to it

Comment: Ohh!! i got it working thank you....!! The version of -more i am using didnt had Assets.js included. I changed it now and its workind well.